# Crystal Reports - subtotal for group header

Tags: crystal-reports, subtotal

I need help with subtotals.

What I have:

A report with 3 groups, the report shows receipts per month. 
It is showing fine with all relevant details and shows which receipts were done on which dates.
The report is showing this:

[image]

These fields are in the Receipt# group header and showing what I need however when I add a subtotal it will show for every receipt, basically I want the report to subtotal like this:

[image]

I have tried moving these fields to the receipt date group which does not work as it then gives me a subtotal for each date and I don't see all receipts for that date.

It might be something small I am missing but I am stumped.

I hope I am making sense here, if not please let me know and I will try my best to clarify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Receipt#` group and add `date group` inplace of receipt.. and place the `Receipt#` under details group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am still getting the same after doing the above. It still only shows subtotals for each receipt# and not each group as shown in table2

Comment: are you sure you have removed `Receipt` grouping and added `Date`? In that case you need to get as expected.... if not can you edit your question to add grouping hierarchy... so that I can understand

Comment: Thanks Siva I came right, looks like there was an issue with the date group field in the stored procedure. What I did to fix it is leave the receipt# group where it was and insert the new date group above it, so receipt# group was group4 and receipt date group was group3. I had duplication issues as well but managed to fix those Thanks for your help.